how to find users who forwarded messages to a group using aiogram 3
how to find users who forwarded messages to a group using aiogram 3. that is, if someone forwards messages in the group, the bot should alert the admin. is it possible to do so? I can't identify the messages forwarded by the bot written in aiogram
I could not identify forwarded messages in aiogram. that is, I could not monitor the messages in this way. Help me Pleeeeeeeease!!!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You did not post any code about what you have tried, but here's a very minimal example how to detect if a message was forwarded. If it does not make sense to you, I suggest that you start by reading the simple example on aiogram documentation front page.
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message()
async def message_handler(message: types.Message):
    if message.forward_origin is not None:
        message_sender = message.from_user.username or message.from_user.full_name

        # Rest of the code to alert the admin about the forwarded message

Also take a look at the Message.forward_origin documentation.

thank you very very big much bro. I didn't add the code to the question because the code I wrote didn't work. I am very pleased with your reply.

i am new to aiogram. I tried the following function for myself.
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Filter,CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message, User
import asyncio
API_TOKEN = "your_token"
ADMIN_CHAT_ID = "admins_id"

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()
from aiogram import Dispatcher, types

dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def start_command(message: Message):
    await message.reply("Welcome to the bot!")
send_messages = [ ]
@dp.message()
async def message_handler(message: types.Message):
    send_messages.append(message)
    for message in send_messages:
        if message.forward_origin is not None:
            message_sender = message.from_user.username or message.from_user.full_name
            user_data = f"User: {message.forward_from.full_name} (@{message.forward_from.username}), " \
                        f"ID: {message.forward_from.id}" \
                        f"message {message}"

            await bot.send_message(ADMIN_CHAT_ID, f"Forwarded message from: {user_data}") 

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

